# get object containing dynamic button jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

I have some dynamically created objects from a jade template which contain buttons. I would like to be able to get the object when the button inside it is clicked. Here is what I currently have

```
  mixin ad(name,media,payout)

.box.box-primary
  .box-header.with-border
    h3.box-title=name

  .box-body
    img(src=media, style='width:130px;height:100px;')
    p.text-muted.text-center="$"+payout
    p.text-muted.text-center preview
  .box-footer.text-right
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='button',id="share",name="share",onclick='getSelf()') Share
```

and the jQuery

```
var getSelf = function() {
   var clickedBtnID = $(this).parent(); 
   alert('you clicked on button #' + clickedBtnID.name);
}
```

I know my jQuery is incorrect because It just prints "undefined" but how would I print the name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, `this` doesn't refer to the `button` element, it refers to `window` object.

You can pass the `this` reference to the function

```
button.btn.btn-primary(type='button',id="share",name="share",onclick='getSelf(this)')
```

Modify your function to accept the reference, which can be used later.

```
var getSelf = function(elem) {
    var clickedBtnID = $(elem).parent(); 
    alert('you clicked on button #' + clickedBtnID.name);
}
```

---

However I would recommend you to use unobtrusive event handler instead of ugly inline click handler(get rid of it).

```
$(function(){
    $("#share").on('click', function(){
        var clickedBtnID = $(this).parent(); 
        alert('you clicked on button #' + clickedBtnID.name);
    });
})
```

Comment: Pass `elem` as an onclick function parameter.

Comment: Better to use @Agalo 's solution to capture the event target instead of trying to capture/pass a "this" reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference to the element which triggered the event using the `event.target` property. The event information is passed as the first parameter to the event handler.

Complete working code.

```js
$('div').click(function(event){
 console.log(event.target.id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>
<div id="div4">div4</div>
<div id="div5">div5</div>
```

Comment: Correct solution, except you forgot to get the `parent()` reference, though something like `event.target.closest('.box.box-primary')` may be safer/more future-proof.